# PHP and the end of October

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have found the weirdest error. And I'm not asking for a fix, I'm just curious if you guys experienced the same and leave it for future reference.

I have the following code, which should output every day of the year 2016

```
$day = "2016-01-01";
for($i = 1; $i<= 365; $i++){
  $day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($day)+60*60*24);
  echo $day."<br/>";    
}
```

But after `30-10-2016` it stops increasing and displays the same date.

PHP Version is 5.6.22. This happens for every year, not only 2016.
Any idea what is causing this?
Is this a problem with this specific PHP Version?
Is this a timezone problem?
Have you experienced the same, or something similar?

What interests me is the cause of this problem. There seems to be something wrong with the strtotime function.

Comment: for PHP Version 5.5.9 - it woking properly and printing all the value

Comment: with PHP 7.0 it's also working as it should.

Comment: I can confirm that error under 5.4.45.

Comment: Daylight Saving time? What is your timezone setting - use UTC.

Comment: omg of course its daylight saving time. I feel so stupid right now :)

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21330285. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a short heads up, I will quickly delete this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding seconds to timestamps to change days/weeks/months can have unexpected results. Try explicitly adding one day...

```
$day = "2016-01-01";
for($i = 1; $i<= 365; $i++){
   $day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 1 day", strtotime($day)));
   echo $day.PHP_EOL;    
}
```

Which timezone is your PHP set to, is there a daylight savings time change at the end of October? - That will cause the date to stick as the day may be 25 hours long.

Comment: I already suspected it to be a timezone problem. Ofc it's daylight savings time

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend the use of [PHP DateTime objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for generation of dates. It's miles more simpler than using procedural code using mathematics to generate it, plus it allows you far more granular control, such as being able to change the interval (say for example you wanted every 2 days rather than every day).

DateTime objects were included in PHP 5.2, so should work fine on your version of PHP.

Example code:

```
$start = new DateTime('2016-12-01');
$end = new DateTime('2016-12-31');

// Use this to add +1 day as the Interval goes _up to_ the date, 
// not inclusive of the date itself
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 

// Set the interval to use, can be P2D if you'd like every 2 days.
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

$dateRange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach($dateRange as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . '<br />';
}
```

Results in:

```
2016-12-01
2016-12-02
...
2016-12-30
2016-12-31
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your code does not work, but this try to restructure your code like this and it will work:

```
$fday = "2016-01-01";
for($i = 1; $i<= 365; $i++){
    $day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fday)+(60*60*24)*$i);
    echo $day."<br/>";
}
```

In here I always start from first of January and add the time diff by multiplying `$i` with the seconds for each day.

It's interesting that your orginal code also won't work when you set that start date to "30-10-2016".